# How to stop last.dump.out and .rda from being saved to file

Tags: r, rstudio

Every time R throws an error in a session, it saves last.dump.out and last.dump.rda to the working directory. I'd like to stop this behaviour. How do I do that? Im using RStudio

Comment: Maybe you set the R option `error` to do this, for instance, in your `~/.Rprofile` file? What does `getOption("error")`?

Comment: getOption("error") returns: `> getOption("error")
(function () 
{
    tb <- .traceback(2L)
    name <- getOption("startup.session.dumpto", "last.dump")
    utils::dump.frames(dumpto = name, to.file = FALSE)
    save(list = name, envir = .GlobalEnv, file = paste0(name, 
        ".rda"))
    dumpto <- get(name, envir = .GlobalEnv)
    rm(list = name, envir = .GlobalEnv)
    sink(file = paste0(name, ".out"))
    on.exit(sink(NULL))
    cat("** Traceback:\n")
    print(tb)
    cat("\n** Dumped frames:\n")
    print(dumpto)
})()`

Comment: Which was in my '~/.Rprofile' as you suggested. Deleted. Thanks!!

Comment: If you still like that behavior when running R in batch mode, you could set that option conditionally on interactive mode, e.g. `if (interactive()) options(error = ...)`.  I use that approach myself.